# Not able to receive the packet as it is coming quickly in python

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-sockets

I am running a socket program in python to communicate with an Embedded Device. I am able to send the packet and get the response immediately, which I can verify it through Wireshark. The problem I am not able to capture it in the my code, but it I am able to see the response in the Wireshark. Below code has send and receive combined. If I split test and I am able to see receive the acknowledgement in the application itself. I suspect the response is very fast to such an extent my application is missing it. Any help is appreciable.

```
import socket
import select
from binascii import unhexlify
from threading import Thread
import time


def client():
    UDP_IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.1.10"
    UDP_PORT_NO = 4010
    clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM  ) 
    clientSock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    packetToSend=""

    messageToSend = raw_input("Message to Send :")

    # if messageTOSend too big send as multiple  packets
    packetsToSend = addpack(messageToSend)

    for count, currentPacket in enumerate(packetsToSend):

        print "\nData Packet %d:"%count

        print currentPacket  
        packetToSend = "".join(map(chr, currentPacket))
        clientSock.sendto(packetToSend, (UDP_IP_ADDRESS, UDP_PORT_NO))
        time.sleep(1)
    print "packets sent"      

def server():
    UDP_IP_ADDRESS = ""
    UDP_PORT_NO = 4011
    print "waiting for data"
    serverSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    serverSock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)

    serverSock.bind((UDP_IP_ADDRESS, UDP_PORT_NO))
    while True:
        data, addr = serverSock.recvfrom(1024)
    time.sleep(5)
    print "Message: ", data



if __name__=='__main__':

    a = 0
    try:
        Thread(target=server).start()
        Thread(target=client).start()
    except Exception, errtxt:
        print errtxt
```

Comment: The loop in `server` discards messages received (i.e. no `print`ing). Other than that, there's nothing functionally wrong with it. The issue may lie with your setup.

Comment: yes, the issue is with my setup. now its working fine. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine, at least the server socket. You just decide not to do anything with the data you receive.

```
while True:
    data, addr = serverSock.recvfrom(1024)
    print "Message: ", data
```

would solve your problem and you would receive the message. Now you just receive in your while loop but the loop never breaks.